# How to set pager on ajax call?

Tags: magento2, pagination, pager

How to set pager on ajax call on a custom table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after digging find this one in your phtml or html file add this and adjust as you requirement.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>paginathing.js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="h1">paginathing.js</h1>
        <p>a jQuery plugin to paginate your DOM easily.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <h3>Paginate  <code>&lt;tabel&gt;</code></h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Nama</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Meroket</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Jungkir Balik</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>Uang ada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>Bukan urusan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>Mangkrak</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <h3>Paginate <code>&lt;li&gt;</code></h3>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">List of item.</h3>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="paginathing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    for (var i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
      $('.list-group').append('<li class="list-group-item"> Item ' + i + '</li>');
    }

    $('.list-group').paginathing({
      perPage: 5,
      limitPagination: 9,
      containerClass: 'panel-footer',
      pageNumbers: true
    })

    $('.table tbody').paginathing({
      perPage: 2,
      insertAfter: '.table',
      pageNumbers: true
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

That will make your table and set pagination and second Here is its JS file

```
    /**
 * jQuery Paginathing
 * Paginate Everything
 *
 * @author Alfred Crosby <https://github.com/alfredcrosby>
 * Inspired from http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Alfred Crosby
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

(function($, window, document) {
    'use strict';

    var Paginator = function(element, options) {
        this.el = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.paginathing.defaults, options);

        this.startPage = 1;
        this.currentPage = 1;
        this.totalItems = this.el.children().length;
        this.totalPages = Math.max(Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.options.perPage), this.options.limitPagination);
        this.container = $('<nav></nav>').addClass(this.options.containerClass);
        this.ul = $('<ul></ul>').addClass(this.options.ulClass);

        this.show(this.startPage);

        return this;
    };

    Paginator.prototype = {
        pagination: function(type, page) {
            var _self = this;
            var li = $('<li></li>');
            var a = $('<a></a>').attr('href', '#');
            var cssClass = type === 'number' ? _self.options.liClass : type;
            var text = '';
            if (type === 'number') {
                text = page;
            } else if (type === 'pageNumbers') {
                // get the page numbers text
                text = _self.paginationNumbersText();
            } else {
                text = _self.paginationText(type);
            }

            li.addClass(cssClass);
            li.data('pagination-type', type);
            li.data('page', page);
            li.append(a.html(text));

            return li;
        },

        paginationText: function(type) {
            return this.options[type + 'Text'];
        },

        paginationNumbersText: function() {
            var _self = this;
            return 'Page ' + _self.currentPage + '/' + _self.totalPages;
        },

        buildPagination: function() {
            var _self = this;
            var pagination = [];
            var prev =
                _self.currentPage - 1 < _self.startPage
                    ? _self.startPage
                    : _self.currentPage - 1;
            var next =
                _self.currentPage + 1 > _self.totalPages
                    ? _self.totalPages
                    : _self.currentPage + 1;

            var start, end;
            var limit = _self.options.limitPagination;

            if (limit) {
                if (_self.currentPage <= Math.ceil(limit / 2) + 1) {
                    start = 1;
                    end = limit;
                } else if (
                    _self.currentPage + Math.floor(limit / 2) >=
                    _self.totalPages
                ) {
                    start = _self.totalPages + 1 - limit;
                    end = _self.totalPages;
                } else {
                    start = _self.currentPage - Math.ceil(limit / 2);
                    end = _self.currentPage + Math.floor(limit / 2);
                }
            } else {
                start = _self.startPage;
                end = _self.totalPages;
            }

            // "First" button
            if (_self.options.firstLast) {
                pagination.push(_self.pagination('first', _self.startPage));
            }

            // "Prev" button
            if (_self.options.prevNext) {
                pagination.push(_self.pagination('prev', prev));
            }

            // Pagination
            for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                pagination.push(_self.pagination('number', i));
            }

            // "Next" button
            if (_self.options.prevNext) {
                pagination.push(_self.pagination('next', next));
            }

            // "Last" button
            if (_self.options.firstLast) {
                pagination.push(_self.pagination('last', _self.totalPages));
            }

            // page numbers
            if (_self.options.pageNumbers) {
                pagination.push(_self.pagination('pageNumbers', _self.currentPage));
            }

            return pagination;
        },

        render: function(page) {
            var _self = this;
            var options = _self.options;
            var pagination = _self.buildPagination();

            // Remove children before re-render (prevent duplicate)
            _self.ul.children().remove();
            _self.ul.append(pagination);

            // Manage active DOM
            var startAt = page === 1 ? 0 : (page - 1) * options.perPage;
            var endAt = page * options.perPage;

            _self.el.children().hide();
            _self.el
                .children()
                .slice(startAt, endAt)
                .show();

            // Manage active state
            _self.ul.children().each(function() {
                var _li = $(this);
                var type = _li.data('pagination-type');

                switch (type) {
                    case 'number':
                        if (_li.data('page') === page) {
                            _li.addClass(options.activeClass);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'first':
                        page === _self.startPage && _li.toggleClass(options.disabledClass);
                        break;
                    case 'last':
                        page === _self.totalPages && _li.toggleClass(options.disabledClass);
                        break;
                    case 'prev':
                        page - 1 < _self.startPage &&
                        _li.toggleClass(options.disabledClass);
                        break;
                    case 'next':
                        page + 1 > _self.totalPages &&
                        _li.toggleClass(options.disabledClass);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });

            // If insertAfter is defined
            if (options.insertAfter) {
                _self.container.append(_self.ul).insertAfter($(options.insertAfter));
            } else {
                _self.el.after(_self.container.append(_self.ul));
            }
        },

        handle: function() {
            var _self = this;
            _self.container.find('li').each(function() {
                var _li = $(this);

                _li.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var page = _li.data('page');

                    _self.currentPage = page;
                    _self.show(page);
                });
            });
        },

        show: function(page) {
            var _self = this;

            _self.render(page);
            _self.handle();
        },
    };

    $.fn.paginathing = function(options) {
        var _self = this;

        return _self.each(function() {
            return new Paginator(this, options);
        });
    };

    $.fn.paginathing.defaults = {
        perPage: 10,
        limitPagination: false,
        prevNext: true,
        firstLast: true,
        prevText: '&laquo;',
        nextText: '&raquo;',
        firstText: 'First',
        lastText: 'Last',
        containerClass: 'pagination-container',
        ulClass: 'pagination',
        liClass: 'page',
        activeClass: 'active',
        disabledClass: 'disabled',
        insertAfter: null,
        pageNumbers: false,
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```